# Recursive function in numba CUDA

Tags: python, cuda, numba

The documentation of numba states that:

> Recursion support in numba is currently limited to self-recursion with explicit type annotation for the function.

I have made this simple device function:

```
@cu.jit(numba.i4(numba.i4), device=True)
def mutate(val: int) -> int:
    if(val < 1):
        return val
    else:
        return mutate(val-1)
```

Which is a fairly simple test of recursion. Now calling this function from my kernel code I get `Untyped global name 'mutate': cannot determine Numba type of <class 
'numba.ir.UndefinedType'>` error.
How else should I specify the type of a function? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Recursion support in numba is currently limited to self-recursion with explicit type annotation for the function.

The first point to make is that the numba documentation **does not** include that text you quote. That comes from [Numba Enhancement Proposal 6](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.38.0/proposals/typing_recursion.html). A proposal to extend the way that numba works. Not a feature of the language/compiler.

That said, this:

```
import numba

@numba.jit(numba.i4(numba.i4))
def mutate(val: int) -> int:
    if(val < 1):
        return val
    else:
        return mutate(val-1)
```

works as you might expect:

```
In [12]: %run recursion.py

In [13]: mutate??
Signature:       mutate(val:int) -> int
Call signature:  mutate(*args, **kwargs)
Type:            CPUDispatcher
String form:     CPUDispatcher(<function mutate at 0x7f77f787f840>)
File:            ~/SO/recursion.py
Source:         
@numba.jit(numba.i4(numba.i4))
def mutate(val: int) -> int:
    if(val < 1):
        return val
    else:
        return mutate(val-1)
Class docstring:
Implementation of user-facing dispatcher objects (i.e. created using
the @jit decorator).
This is an abstract base class. Subclasses should define the targetdescr
class attribute.
Init docstring: 
Parameters
----------
py_func: function object to be compiled
locals: dict, optional
    Mapping of local variable names to Numba types.  Used to override
    the types deduced by the type inference engine.
targetoptions: dict, optional
    Target-specific config options.
impl_kind: str
    Select the compiler mode for `@jit` and `@generated_jit`
pipeline_class: type numba.compiler.BasePipeline
    The compiler pipeline type.

In [14]: print(mutate(10))
0
```

But the Numba CUDA compiler (and I am guessing compilation in nopython mode) will not compile equivalent code, as you have discovered. From that, plus the fact that nowhere in the Numba CUDA documentation is recursion mentioned, I would conclude that the Numba CUDA compiler doesn't support recursion.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. But before I close the question, can you verify that numba CUDA jit function discards the `argType` parameter altogether? I read some of the code and it seems that the property is ignored